# Why does this compile without errors? (Returning a type that doesn't subclass the stated returned type)

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've inherited `std::list` to allow 'psuedo random access' with the `[]` operator.

```
#include <list>
template <typename T>
class rlist : public std::list<T> {
    T& operator[](int index){
        typename std::list<T>::iterator iterator;
        int pos;
        for (iterator = this->begin(), pos = 0; iterator != this->end(); iterator++, pos++)
            if (pos == index)
                return *iterator;
        return inexistent_element();
    }

    class inexistent_element {

    };
};
```

`inexistent_element` does not yet inherit `T`, so this shouldn't compile. But it compiles. Also I'm pretty sure C++ shouldn't allow me to pass by non-const reference an object that was created inline.

I'm using Code::Blocks IDE with MinGW gcc compiler. I'd like to know why this compiles.

Comment: Are you sure you have instantiated this `operator[]` function somewhere in your code?

Comment: Compiler errors will come for sure if you instantiate the function. But in any case, this class looks like a really, really bad idea. The biggest question is why you use a `std::list` if you want random access with `[]`.

Comment: And if you really need this, then don't inherit. Create a free-standing function that takes a `std::list` and an `int` index.

Comment: With templates you don't get so many errors as you do with non-templated classes unless you actually use them.

Comment: In C++11 this code becomes pointless, since `std::list` has a constant time `size()` function, and you can simply combine `size()` and `std::next(begin(), n)`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl is correct here, this is really not a problem where traditional OOP is the answer. Inheriting from the standard library containers is not something you want to do and the usually preferred alternative of composition is not going to be any better since you will have to expose the entirety of the container's interface through your encapsulating class. `template <typename T> const T& UtilityFunctionsNamespace::listElementAt(const std::list<T> &list, size_t index);` is the way I would go.

Comment: When you need random access, you'd better use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4):

The member function `operator[]` was never instantiated by you. How I know that? It's private.

Note that instantiating a class does not automatically instantiate its member functions ([temp.inst]/1):

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
>   the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the
>   definitions or default arguments, of the class member functions,
>   member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members and
>   member templates;

Comment: Why private? Would it change something if it were public?

Comment: @user3834459 I just said that you couldn't have instantiated (used) it since it is private. If it was public you could have used it, couldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, as others have pointed out, you've never actually instantiated the
`operator[]`; the compiler is not required to diagnose the case where no legal
instantionations are possible, and different compilers are more or less
aggressive in this.  (MSC will diagnose almost nothing without an
instantiation; g++ will diagnose most cases where there can be no legal
instantiation.)

But of course, there can be legal instantiations of your function.
`inexisting_element` may not have a base class, but `T` could have a
non-explicit constructor taking an `inexisting_element` by const reference, so
the compiler cannot legally reject this code until it knows `T`; i.e. the
function has been instantiated.